# Using .htaccess to use subdirectory as a parameter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've had a real tough time trying to search for the exact htaccess code that will allow me to do the following:

Visiting: http://www.domain.com/wildcard

Should show: http://www.domain.com/

But the URL should still read: http://www.domain.com/wildcard

So basically a transparent redirection... seems fairly straight-forward, but surprisingly hard to search for. The PHP in index.php is already set up to parse the subdirectory and read it as a parameter, but unfortunately my client never supplied me with the .htaccess file. #developerproblems

Thanks!

Comment: What .htaccess rules have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need this `ErrorDocument 404` line at top of your .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /
```

This will show home page for any request that is not a file or directory and results in a 404.

Comment: Simple, and elegant enough for my site where an official 404 page isn't actually needed. Thanks!

Comment: for it is more friendly for SEO in this case. I voted for it.

Answer (score 0):

We will suppose that you have to receive a url parameter called `param` so your rewrite rule should be:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?param=$1 [L]
```

By this way any `http://www.domain.com/AnythingHere` will render the contents of `http://www.domain.com/?param=AnythingHere` so the home page is rendered.

***However, such solutions, they are not change the contents, they may leads to SEO problems for repeated contents, So the solution of [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava) is better for SEO according to your usage.***